onClick not working on div element but works on button element
I'm using a toggle to show an element using useReducer in NextJs. If I were to put the onClick function on a div, it does not fire but when I use a button it does. Any insight on this behavior?
const [isOpen, toggleIsOpen] = useReducer((state) => {        
    return !state
}, false)

<button onClick={toggleIsOpen}>TOGGLE</button>

This works
<div className='ham float-end' onClick={toggleIsOpen}>
    ...
</div>

This doesn't

It should work actually, can you please check with your css, else remove the css and check once.

Agreed with Suganth. There might be another factor that prevents click from happening. Please check the CSS applied to "ham" or "float-end" class, maybe it meddles with pointer-events or z-index or could be anything.

Change
<div className='ham float-end' onClick={toggleIsOpen}>
to
<div className='ham float-end' onClick={() => toggleIsOpen()}>

This will not work! It should be like onClick={()=>toggleIsOpen()}
